# Use 2 advanced data tables sb admin 2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, admin, frontend

I starting using bootstrap sb admin 2. I have a problem in having 2 advanced data tables. the first one is working, i am copy pasting to have a second one and the pagination is lost. Here is the picture

[image]

The problem is that both have the same id. Is there a solution on this?

Thanks!

P.S. Sorry for bad tags I could not find the right ones..

Answer (score 1):

If someone else have the same problem on the bottom of tables.html there is this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            responsive: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Should have seen it. Anyway glad if somene find this useful